# Error with popup overlay in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In OpenLayers (OL) 3.15.0 I declare a popup contains like :

```
popup = $(eval('<div id="popup"><p>My contain</p></div>'));
```

And after, I declare my overly with this popup element :

```
var overlay_popup = new ol.Overlay({
                        element: popup
                    });
```

On OL 3.7.0 I've any problem all was okay.

But now with this new version of OL (3.15.0) Firebug say :

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface
>   Node.

What can I do for working ?

Answer (score 1):

You must declare this : `element: popup[0]`